# Java Cucumber with optional Datatable parameter

Tags: java, cucumber

I am trying to write a component test were it would be ideal where I can either pass in the values if needed to configure or else use a default values.

Employee.class

```
public class Employee {
public static final Employee DEFAULT_EMPLOYEE = Employee.builder()
.employeName("Jack")
.employeNumber(01)
.build();


  String employeeName;
  Integer employeeNumber;
....
}
```

employee.feature

```
Given a employee is created
or
Given a employee is created
| employeeName | employeeNumber | 
| John         | 123.           |
```

employeeStep.java

```
@When("a/the employee is created")
  public void createEmployee(Employee employee){
  service.createEmpoyee(employee);
}
```

EmployeeTransformer.java

```
public class EmployeeTransformer {

@DataTableType
public Employee transform(Map<String, String> data) {
  EmployeeBuilder eb = DEFAULT_EMPLOYEE.toBuilder();

  Optional.ofNullable(data.get(EMPLOYEEE_NAME))
  .map(String::valueOf)
  .ifPresent(eb::employeeName);

  ....

  return eb.build();
 }
}
```

Above transformer handles the step when dataTable parameters is passed in the step. The problem is that when a step with no data table is added to a scenario, it throws the following exception:

```
io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Step [Given a employee is created] is defined with 1 parameters at 'com. createEmployee.steps. employeeStep. createEmployee(io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable)'. However, the gherkin step has 0 arguments.
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a real use case. If a business user was tasked to create a BDD test case, how is this user supposed to know that `Given a employee is created` actually means `Given no employee is created`? While I think I get what you are trying to do, the over complication seems to be pointless. Creating an employee should have a 1-many result.

Comment: `Given a employee is created` will always create an employee, if would use the default values if not presented in the dataTable

Comment: I stand corrected. I missed that detail in your code example.

Comment: By the way, what happens when you run your code?

Comment: io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Step [Given a employee is created] is defined with 1 parameters at 'com. createEmployee.steps. employeeStep. createEmployee(io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable)'.
However, the gherkin step has 0 arguments.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your question and put the exception as part of it. For future reference, this is relevant part of the issue and should always be included in the description of your problem so that other people have the complete picture before attempting to answer your questions.

Comment: I hope my answer is clear enough. I would appreciate an upvote if the answer is helpful and to select it as the answer if it fully addressed your issue.

Comment: Yh, its the Gherkin issue, I've decided to go ahead with multiple step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined a step definition that takes a `DataTable` argument but your example to use a default employee uses a step with zero arguments. That is not valid in Gherkins. In fact, this is not valid in Java!

When you create a function in Java

```
public void myMethod(String arg) {
...
}
```

Even if the method accept a `null` value, I must pass a reference to something when I call that method, even if the value is `null`. This

```
myObj.myMethod();
```

is not the same as

```
myObj.myMethod(null);
```

Those are two different methods. Don't you agree? **Passing no arguments to a function is not the same as passing null arguments.** To make it more relevant to your specific issue, passing no `DataTable` is not the same as passing a null `DataTable`, or passing no `DataTable` rows is not the same as passing empty or null rows. This is what the exception is telling you. You are passing nothing to a function that expects something to be passed to it.

Although I have never taken this approach, I believe you MUST add an empty row to your `DataTable` for your default case to work and I am not even sure if that would work either. Try something like this

```
Given a employee is created
| employeeName | employeeNumber |
|              |                |
| John         | 123.           |
```

Now it is up to Gherkin to see if the above case is supported. But the above is the equivalent (in Java) of passing **null** or empty arguments rather than **no** arguments. That said, the above, if it works, I am not sure if it will create a null map. For starters, I don't know what version of Cucumber you are using. I think newer versions replace empty cells with `null` but I am not certain how this will work, even if you use a newer version, since the key value is null in the above example. This solution may not fully work, but it should get you close.

Comment: @PruthviLalji make sure you add comments to your scenario that the empty row is to support "default user" creation. You and your current teammates know that now, but if someone new comes in and you aren't there to explain it, it might take a while for them to figure this out. Make the intent clear with good comments!

Comment: good shout. Thank @hfontanez